# Linux is unable to find specified path

Tags: python, import, path, operating-system

My python script is running on Windows without any issues. But the same script has to run on a Linux machine as well. When ran, it prompts that the specified path is non-existent. Note that variable "path" is pointing to a cloud server

I subsequently tried the os.path.join function after looking through some forums, which also failed

```
import os
import re
import sys

#List .xlsx files followed by the string ESC
path = '\\\\cloudnetworkonlinuxserver'
path2 = 'DBX'
path3 = 'SrcFiles'
path4 = 'MEBilling'
path5 = 'ParmFiles'

filenames = os.listdir(os.path.join(path, path2, path3, path4))
for filename in filenames:
    getdate = re.search('(?<=ESC_)\w+', filename)

    #Replace '_' with '-'
    if getdate:
        date = getdate.group(0).replace('_', '-')
        print('The following ESC file has date', date)

#Create .prm file with following body
f = open(os.path.join(path, path2, path5, "wf_SC_Monthend_Billing_XLS" + "." + "prm"), 'w')

#f.write cannot take more than one argument. Write variables such
a = '$$WF_PERIOD='
b = date

#Write in body of file
f.write("[Global]\n")
f.write('%s%s' % (a,b,))

#Close writing process
f.close
```

What other methods are there in specifying a path that is compatible with those both operating systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `\\cloudnetworkonlinuxserver` is a Samba share: This path alone is Windows-specific. Depending on the platform, there may be a different way how this share would be accessed.

On Linux, you'd have to [mount this share](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client) at some physical path first, for example `/mnt/cloudshare`. Then you'd access this path instead.

You should take this path from a command line argument or environment variable so that the appropriate path can be passed depending on what is correct in each environment.

Or, in case this should be part of the script, you'd have to make your script take care of mounting the share in case the environment is Linux (and ideally also unmounting it when no longer needed).